# php hashing the ID and after chech if is true

Tags: php, security, hash

I wrote scripct and it works very well, but I would like to hash ID of answer not to available discover correct answer.

So my current code looks this:

```
foreach($result2 as $row)
{
   $odpowiedz = $row['Tresc_odpowiedzi'];
   $value= $row['ID'];
   echo "<p><input type=\"radio\" name=\"odp\" value=\"$value\" />$odpowiedz</p>";
} // pobranie wartosci ID pytania z bazy i wpisanie go jako value


$zapytanie3 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM odpowiedzi WHERE ID = :ID_odpowiedzi'); //pobranie wedlud kategorii zdefiniowanej w 'bindValue'
$zapytanie3 -> bindValue(':ID_odpowiedzi',$_POST['odp'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$zapytanie3 -> execute();
$result3 = $zapytanie3 -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//pobranie danej odpowiedzi, aby sprawdzic czy prawidlowa
```

no I would like to hash $value, so it is easy: `$licznik_odp = hash( 'sha256', $value.$sald);`, but I don't know how to check if it is ID number 254 or not, etc.

because in `$zapytanie3 -> bindValue(':ID_odpowiedzi',$_POST['odp'], PDO::PARAM_INT);` I have to write ID of answer (before hashing it is $row['ID'])

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: I know you probably did your best, but I'm having a hard time understanding your question.  If you could edit it to correct your typos and/or misspellings and clarify statements it would be very helpful.

Comment: you can delete this subject or close it, because I have just done it myself :)

Comment: Can you post your solution or something similar so that people in the future will benefit?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no problem, maybe I will help other people :)

I add extra column HASH in MySQL in table odpowiedzi (answers)
and when I add some question with answers, every answer I hashed:

```
$id = $rekord['ID'];
$hash_a = hash( 'sha256', $a.'sold'.$id);
```

$id - it is ID of question

$a - it is one answer with $_POST

$hash_a - it is hashing answer with id

in value of radio I write this hash like this:

```
$value = $row['Hash'];
                echo "<p><input type=\"radio\" name=\"odp\" value=\"$value\" id=\"$value\" /><label for=\"$value\">$odpowiedz</label></p>";
and in checking question I changed my query:
```

and for the end I check it if this hash exist in mySQL

```
$zapytanie3 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM odpowiedzi WHERE Hash = :Hash'); //pobranie wedlud kategorii zdefiniowanej w 'bindValue'
            $zapytanie3 -> bindValue(':Hash',$_POST['odp'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

It is all, I think that noone can check if correct in HTML code, because all answers are hashing :)